# Cannot open php file, the source file seems empty

Tags: php, apache

When I try to open the file `register.php` from the localhost(localhost/PrimaAppAndroid/register.php), the page remains white, and if I try to see the source file it is empty. If I leave the php part from `register.php`, it works fine even if I don't change the extension php in html.

I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page) and I added `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` at the end of my `apache2.conf` file but nothing changed. How can  fix this?

Here the sources:
register.php

```
<?php 
/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
    require("config.inc.php");
?>

<h1>Register</h1> 
<form action="register.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Register New User" /> 
</form>
```

config.inc.php:

```
<?php 

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "root"
    $password = "root"
    $host = "localhost"
    $dbname = "cinemapreverificasql"

    // Tis is the way we saw in class
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Errore nella connessione MySQL");
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or ide("Database inesistente");
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Check your PHP error log.

Comment: Allowing your app to connect to your db as root is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and I explain you here the motivation: in the school where I go in the test we have to use this method to connect, so I would like try it an see if it works, and I connect as a root because this is not the definitive application, I have just created the database and I just try to connect it

Comment: did you tried my suggestions?

Comment: Yes, with yours it works, and are the most complete, thanks @ChristianGiupponi

Comment: why did you remove the accept mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao Giacomotb,
if you post your code correctly there is a typo in your `config.inc.php` file.

```
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or ide("Database inesistente");
```

as you can see at the end you use the `die` function but you wrote `ide`, just fix it and it works

plus you forgot the semicolon at the end of your php variables.

```
$username = "root"
    $password = "root"
    $host = "localhost"
    $dbname = "cinemapreverificasql"
```

must be

```
$username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "cinemapreverificasql";
```

Answer (score 2):

No semi-colons in `config.inc.php` variables?

Answer (score 2):

another possible source of the error:

```
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or ide("Database inesistente");
```

should probably be

```
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or die("Database inesistente");
```

Answer (score 1):

i noticed you code having errors as (;) is missing in the end of varaiables you declare.

```
<?php 

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "cinemapreverificasql";

    // Tis is the way we saw in class
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Errore nella connessione MySQL");
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or ide("Database inesistente");
?>
```

and the other thing try by renaming your file which is config.inc.php and repalce name to config_inc.php

Comment: The file name is quite legal, so your suggestion to rename it is pointless.